# How to load Cronjob using whenever on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cron

I make a cronjob in my app app by using whenever gem

```
set :output, {:error => "log/cron_error_log.log" , :standard => "log/cron_log.log" }
every :day, :at => '01:50pm' do
  runner "Welcome.index"
end
```

Locally it works great but now I want to deploy it on heroku. I have two questions
1) I can't find any complete tutorial loading cronjob on heroku , if anyone have kindly give link

2) one thing learn is to add install add-on but they are paid, either free-one available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to use https://elements.heroku.com/addons/scheduler for running timed jobs
its really easy to set up 
[image]

you say when you want to run it and you the option of every 10 min, hourly, or daily and what kind of processor for the job.

Comment: either its free or paid?

Comment: Please verify your account to install this add-on plan (please enter a credit card) For more information, see https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/billing Verify now at https://heroku.com/verify........................which mean its paid?

Comment: Heroku is not a free service, they make it easy to start but if you are running cron its no longer a demo its production baby

Comment: Ok thanks..Now i tell my client to buy an account on hereoku :)

Comment: If you have to run a process every day then yes

Comment: I can't imagine it would be more than 14 - 20 per month at first

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Heroku scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler)

It's free and simple to use. Just upload the task with Your project on heroku and set the options via web-interface. Also, for test You can run the task via heroku bash.

Comment: in it also ask for scheduler addon which is paid

Comment: Are You sure? I had already installed this addon before and everything was free. And now And now I see Standard at $0/mo, unlimited jobs
https://elements.heroku.com/addons/scheduler

Comment: this is not really free it does uses dyno memory and you only have so much

Comment: Yes when I run that command it give........ Please verify your account to install this add-on plan (please enter a credit card) For more information, see https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/billing Verify now at https://heroku.com/verify .............and for that verification it require credit card info etc